# How to use JSON-B to serialize a transient property?

Tags: jax-rs, jsonb

Given a

```java
public class Foo {

    private String x;
    transient private String y;

    public String getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }   

    public String getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(String y) {
        this.y = y;
    }   

}
```

How can you instruct JSON-B to serialise property `y`?

This is a case where type `Foo` is used in a JPA context (`@Entity`) where `transient` indicates a property should not be persisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `transient` keyword, annotate the field with the `@javax.persistence.Transient` annotation.

i.e.

```java
    @Transient
    private String y;
```

Effectively this makes the property available to JSON-B for serialisation.